# Existence of an $\alpha$-regular measure with positive measure on a binary digits do not have a limiting frequency

Tags: fractals, hausdorff-dimension, probabilistic-number-theory, hausdorff-measure

let $$X=\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}2^{-n}:a_{n}\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} ,\liminf\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}<\limsup\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right\} $$

I'm studying fractal geometry and I've encountered the following question: Is there an $\alpha$-regular measure giving $X$ positive measure?

Now, I've noticed that the Lebesgue measure of $X$ must be zero, simply by looking at its complement, and by the LLN the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ exists almost surely, hence $X^{c}$ has Lebesgue measure 0. I'm not sure how to proceed, and would be happy for any suggestions.
In general I'm trying to find the Hausdorff dimension of $X$.

Comment: What is an $\alpha$-regular measure?

Comment: We say a measure $\mu$ is $\alpha$-regular if there's a constant C such that $\mu\left(B_{r}\left(x\right)\right)\leq C\cdot r^{\alpha}$ for every $x, r$

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at *On simply normal numbers to different bases*, by Becher, Bugeaud and Slaman (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-015-1209-9).  An instance of the main theorem of that paper is that the set of real numbers that are not simply normal in base 2 has full Hausdorff dimension.  The method of the paper is to ensure failures of simple normality by introducing oscillations in the associated discrepancy function, which ensures the inequality that you requested.